# Scale ColorFunction in ListContourPlot for Log Scale

Tags: plotting, color, legending, logarithmic-scale

I am trying to create a ListContourPlot where the z values span several orders of magnitude. I've created a color function using ColorData and successfully created a BarLegend in the log scale which spans the minimum and maximum values being plotted. However, the gradient of the ColorData is scaling in such a way that values with lower magnitudes are all colored in a very similar manner.

How can I adjust the scaling of the gradient within the ColorFunction such that the values in the lower regions are more visible?

The table I'm creating takes some time to run--I am also including its output below.

```
Timing[NHATcapH2Table = 
  Table[{ninftable[[k]], 
    TempTable[[j]], zetaizcxH2table[[1]]*
     IsnH2[1, j, k, rhoLH2]}, {j, 1, 
    Dimensions[TempTable][[1]]}, {k, 1, Dimensions[ninftable][[1]]}]]

{1080.5, {{{1000000000000000, 1, 1.12794*10^17}, {10000000000000000, 
    1, 1.12794*10^18}, {100000000000000000, 1, 
    1.12794*10^19}, {1000000000000000000, 1, 
    1.12794*10^20}, {10000000000000000000, 1, 
    1.12794*10^21}, {100000000000000000000, 1, 
    1.12794*10^22}, {1000000000000000000000, 1, 
    1.12794*10^23}}, {{1000000000000000, 3, 
    9.56979*10^16}, {10000000000000000, 3, 
    9.56979*10^17}, {100000000000000000, 3, 
    9.56979*10^18}, {1000000000000000000, 3, 
    9.56979*10^19}, {10000000000000000000, 3, 
    9.56979*10^20}, {100000000000000000000, 3, 
    9.56979*10^21}, {1000000000000000000000, 3, 
    9.56979*10^22}}, {{1000000000000000, 5, 
    1.00905*10^17}, {10000000000000000, 5, 
    1.00905*10^18}, {100000000000000000, 5, 
    1.00905*10^19}, {1000000000000000000, 5, 
    1.00905*10^20}, {10000000000000000000, 5, 
    1.00905*10^21}, {100000000000000000000, 5, 
    1.00905*10^22}, {1000000000000000000000, 5, 
    1.00905*10^23}}, {{1000000000000000, 10, 
    1.10309*10^17}, {10000000000000000, 10, 
    1.10309*10^18}, {100000000000000000, 10, 
    1.10309*10^19}, {1000000000000000000, 10, 
    1.10309*10^20}, {10000000000000000000, 10, 
    1.10309*10^21}, {100000000000000000000, 10, 
    1.10309*10^22}, {1000000000000000000000, 10, 
    1.10309*10^23}}, {{1000000000000000, 15, 
    1.11826*10^17}, {10000000000000000, 15, 
    1.11826*10^18}, {100000000000000000, 15, 
    1.11826*10^19}, {1000000000000000000, 15, 
    1.11826*10^20}, {10000000000000000000, 15, 
    1.11826*10^21}, {100000000000000000000, 15, 
    1.11826*10^22}, {1000000000000000000000, 15, 
    1.11826*10^23}}, {{1000000000000000, 25, 
    1.12548*10^17}, {10000000000000000, 25, 
    1.12548*10^18}, {100000000000000000, 25, 
    1.12548*10^19}, {1000000000000000000, 25, 
    1.12548*10^20}, {10000000000000000000, 25, 
    1.12548*10^21}, {100000000000000000000, 25, 
    1.12548*10^22}, {1000000000000000000000, 25, 
    1.12548*10^23}}, {{1000000000000000, 40, 
    1.1281*10^17}, {10000000000000000, 40, 
    1.1281*10^18}, {100000000000000000, 40, 
    1.1281*10^19}, {1000000000000000000, 40, 
    1.1281*10^20}, {10000000000000000000, 40, 
    1.1281*10^21}, {100000000000000000000, 40, 
    1.1281*10^22}, {1000000000000000000000, 40, 
    1.1281*10^23}}, {{1000000000000000, 50, 
    1.12879*10^17}, {10000000000000000, 50, 
    1.12879*10^18}, {100000000000000000, 50, 
    1.12879*10^19}, {1000000000000000000, 50, 
    1.12879*10^20}, {10000000000000000000, 50, 
    1.12879*10^21}, {100000000000000000000, 50, 
    1.12879*10^22}, {1000000000000000000000, 50, 
    1.12879*10^23}}, {{1000000000000000, 60, 
    1.12919*10^17}, {10000000000000000, 60, 
    1.12919*10^18}, {100000000000000000, 60, 
    1.12919*10^19}, {1000000000000000000, 60, 
    1.12919*10^20}, {10000000000000000000, 60, 
    1.12919*10^21}, {100000000000000000000, 60, 
    1.12919*10^22}, {1000000000000000000000, 60, 
    1.12919*10^23}}, {{1000000000000000, 75, 
    1.12957*10^17}, {10000000000000000, 75, 
    1.12957*10^18}, {100000000000000000, 75, 
    1.12957*10^19}, {1000000000000000000, 75, 
    1.12957*10^20}, {10000000000000000000, 75, 
    1.12957*10^21}, {100000000000000000000, 75, 
    1.12957*10^22}, {1000000000000000000000, 75, 1.12957*10^23}}}}

minn = Flatten[
    Pick[NHATcapH2Table, #, Min@#] &@
     NHATcapH2Table[[All, All, 3]]][[3]];
maxx = Flatten[
    Pick[NHATcapH2Table, #, Max@#] &@
     NHATcapH2Table[[All, All, 3]]][[3]];

colfunct = ColorData["SunsetColors"][#/ maxx] &
legt = BarLegend[{colfunct, {minn, maxx}}, 
  Power[10, 
   Range[MantissaExponent[minn][[2]], MantissaExponent[maxx][[2]]]]]

ListContourPlot[Flatten[NHATcapH2Table, 1], 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None}, Contours -> 20, PlotRange -> Full,
  ColorFunction -> colfunct, PlotLegends -> legt, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

Comment: The definitions of `minn` and `maxx` can be simplified to `{minn, maxx} = MinMax[Flatten[NHATcapH2Table, 1][[All, 3]]];`

Comment: That is a lot cleaner, thank you!